# ios7 UITableView Height , changed but return to default

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

i'm newer.
i find a strange problem about UITableview.

when the uitableview be loaded, the height is 400.
and then ,in program, i change the uitableview's height

```
CGRect talkListFrame = _talkList.frame;
talkListFrame.size.height = _talkListOriginalHeight -keyboardSize.height;
[_talkList setFrame:talkListFrame];
```

it was good, i changed the height of the uitableview(talkList).
but ,when i put data to the uitableview, the height of uitableview return to 400.
※i used a custom uitableviewcell, just put a label in the cell.

```
UILabel *lable = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:6];
lable.text =@"xxxx";
```

if i do not use a custom uitablecell, it was good,the height not return.

```
cell.textLabel.text =@"";
```

why? the custom cell is the problem

Comment: Looks like you are talking about the row height of the table. Please let me know if I am right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When showing the keyboard don't change the `frame`. Change `contentInset`.

I do it like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification{

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

        UIEdgeInsets tableViewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardFrame.size.height, 0);
        _talkList.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableViewInsets;
        _talkList.contentInset = tableViewInsets;

    }completion:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

        UIEdgeInsets tableViewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        _talkList.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableViewInsets;
        _talkList.contentInset = tableViewInsets;

    }completion:nil];
}
```